# Suppose $f$ is injective but $g$ is not. Is it true that $g \circ f$ is not injective?

Tags: functions

> Suppose $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is injective but $g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is not. Is that necessarily true that $g \circ f$ is not injective?

If we considered finite domains, it'd pretty straightforward to show that $g \circ f$ might be injective. For example, we can take $f = \{(3,5)\}$ and $g = \{(1,2),(2,2),(5,8)\}$. Then clearly $g$ is not injective but $g \circ f = \{(3,8)\}$ is.

**What about the case where the domain of both functions is $\mathbb R$?**

---

There seem to be case (apparently rare one), where $g \circ f$ will not be injective, i.e

> Suppose $f$ is injective but $g$ is not. Further suppose that for some $x_1,x_2$ such that $g(x_1) = g(x_2)$ (we can find such $x_1,x_2$ because $g$ is not injective), there exist $v_1,v_2$ such that $f(v_1) = x_1$ and $f(v_2) = x_2$.

Then clearly we have $g(f(v_1) = g(f(v_2))$, implying that $g \circ f$ will not be injective.

Comment: if you want an example on $\mathbb R$ just alter $x\mapsto x$ at some distinct points.

Comment: $f(x) = e^x$, $g(x) = |x|$.

Comment: $g$ constant, $f$ any injective.

Comment: I see, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is injective and maps $\Bbb{R}$ onto a subset $X \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ such that $g$ is injective on $X$, then the composite $g \circ f$ will be injective, even if $g$ is not injective on all of $\Bbb{R}$. E.g., take $f = \arctan$ and $g = \sin$.